# Проблема с SLL сертификатом. Вебмастер yandex

Tags: ssl

Проблема заключается в том что я выдал на сайт SSL сертификат от letsencrypt. Вебмастер выдаёт критическую ошибку для сайта. Как можно решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Время пройдёт, ошибка уйдёт. Яндекс не тороплив.

Comment: Как именно вы выдали сертификат на сайт? Опишите процесс, какие файлы использовали, какие конфиги писали

Comment: дело в том что эта ошибка висит достаточно давно, м.б. она висела из-за того что в конфиге nginx висел поддомен, на который не был выдан сертификат. Не знаю. Сколько примерно времени ему нужно?

Comment: Выдавал через утилиту certbot, выбрал далее домен нужный и выдавал. На двух других сайтах с тем же процессом не было проблем